# Derived class not running code in _init_

Tags: python

Why would the following code not print `"Hello"`?

```
# C derives from B, which derives from A, which derives from object
class D(C):
  def _init_(self, *args, **kw):
    print "Hello"


foo = D('some_text')
```

I have tested this in Python 2.7 with no luck.

I am not including the code of `C`, `B` and `A`, but why would that matter anyway?

I am happy to include their definitions, but I didn't want to complicate the code above unnecessarily.

Comment: You're missing two undescores from your definition of `__init__`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use *double* underscores:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
```

The method `_init_` has no special meaning to Python and won't be called when instantiating.

Comment: Geez. Unbelievable. Thanks Martijn. Sorry for such a silly question.

Answer (score 2):

```
# C derives from B, which derives from A, which derives from object
class D(C):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    print "Hello"


foo = D('some_text')
```

double underscores.